# NSURLConnection crashes when proxy is set

Tags: ios, proxy

I set proxy settings from Wi-Fi menu to a random address and port. After that when I call (on main thread or background thread)

```
resultData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
```

my app crashes while getting proxy settings with `CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()`. Even if I call this method `CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()` explicitly it crashes.

This happens just on iOS 6. If I call CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings() in `AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. or a couple of functions before before my connection call no crash happens. But I'm certain about that everything is on main thread.

[image: stack]

It seems like over-releasing a string object.